# If $u : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ satisfies $u' + 2\pi x u = 0$, why does $\hat{u}$ (the Fourier transform) also satisfy this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to understand why if a function $u : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ satisfies the differential equation $u' + 2\pi x u = 0$, then so does the Fourier transform.

The properties I have that I can use are:  $\widehat{\frac{du}{dx}}(\xi) = 2 \pi i \xi \hat{u}(\xi)$, and also $-\widehat{2 \pi i x u}(\xi) = \frac{d\hat{u}}{d\xi}(\xi)$.

I think this is supposed to be really simple, but I've tried substituting the second property with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ u' = -2\pi x u, $$
so transforming both sides we have:
$$ 2\pi i\xi\, \widehat{u}(\xi) = -i \widehat{u}'(\xi).$$

Comment: So it really was simple.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is a theory about the empty set $\ldots$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I do not understand. $u(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ is a very well-behaved solution of the ODE.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Yes, but it helps  to be mentioned. It could have been that there is no reasonable $u$ satisfying the claim.